# Returning tasks for each session in Neo4J (list of lists)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using Neo4J for a mentor platform I'm building and I'm stumped by the following:

Given the following nodes and properties:

```
Mentor{ login, ... }
Mentee{ login, ... }
Session{ notes, ... }
Task{ complete, name }
```

And the following associations:

```
// each session has 1 mentor and 1 mentee
(Mentor)<-[:HAS]-(Session)-[:HAS]->(Mentee)

// each task is FOR one person (a Mentor or Mentee)
// each task is FROM one Session
(Session)<-[:FROM]-(Task)-[:FOR]->(Mentor or Mentee)
```

What's the best way to query this data to produce an API response in the following shape? Similarly, is this a reasonable way to model the data? Maybe something with `coalesce`?

```js
{
  mentor: { login: '...', /* ... */ },
  mentee: { login: '...', /* ... */ },
  sessions: [
    {
      notes,
      /* ... */
      mentorTasks: [{ id, name, complete }],
      menteeTasks: [{ id, name, complete }]
  ]
```

I first tried:

```
MATCH (mentor:Mentor{ github: "mentorlogin" })
MATCH (session:Session)-[:HAS]->(mentee:Mentee{ github: "menteelogin" })
OPTIONAL MATCH (mentor)<-[:FOR]-(mentorTask:Task)-[:FROM]->(session)
OPTIONAL MATCH (mentee)<-[:FOR]-(menteeTask:Task)-[:FROM]->(session)

RETURN
  mentor,
  mentee,
  session,
  COLLECT(DISTINCT mentorTask) as mentorTasks,
  COLLECT(DISTINCT menteeTask) as menteeTasks

ORDER BY session.date DESC
```

But that's janky - The mentor and mentee data is returned many times, and it's completely gone if the mentee has no sessions.

This seems more appropriate, but I'm not sure how to fold in the tasks:

```
MATCH (mentor:Mentor{ github: "mentorlogin" })
MATCH (mentee:Mentee{ github: "menteelogin })
OPTIONAL MATCH (session:Session)-[:HAS]->(mentee)
OPTIONAL MATCH (mentor)<-[:FOR]-(mentorTask:Task)-[:FROM]->(session)
OPTIONAL MATCH (mentee)<-[:FOR]-(menteeTask:Task)-[:FROM]->(session)

RETURN
  mentor,
  mentee,
  COLLECT(DISTINCT session) as sessions
```

---

**EDIT: Working**! thanks to a prompt response from Graphileon. I made a few modifications:

- changed `MATCH` statement so it returns the mentor and mentee even if there are no sessions
- sort sessions by date (most recent first)
- return all node properties, instead of whitelisting

```
MATCH (mentor:Mentor{ github: $mentorGithub })
MATCH (mentee:Mentee{ github: $menteeGithub })

RETURN DISTINCT {
  mentor: mentor{ .*, id: toString(id(mentor)) },
  mentee: mentee{ .*, id: toString(id(mentee)) },
  sessions: apoc.coll.sortMaps([(mentor:Mentor)<-[:HAS]-(session:Session)-[:HAS]->(mentee:Mentee) |
    session{
      .*,
      id: toString(id(session)),
      mentorTasks: [
        (session)<-[:FROM]-(task:Task)-[:FOR]->(mentor) |
        task{ .*, id: toString(id(task)) }
      ],
      menteeTasks: [
        (session)<-[:FROM]-(task:Task)-[:FOR]->(mentee) |
        task{ .*, id: toString(id(task)) }
      ]
    }
  ], "date")
} AS result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you would have these data:

[image]

You can do something along these lines, with nested [pattern comprehensions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension)

```
MATCH (mentor:Mentor)<-[:HAS]-(:Session)-[:HAS]->(mentee:Mentee)
RETURN DISTINCT {
        mentor: {id:id(mentor), name: mentor.name},
        mentee: {id:id(mentee), name: mentee.name},
        sessions: [(mentor:Mentor)<-[:HAS]-(session:Session)-[:HAS]->(mentee:Mentee) | 
                      { id: id(session),
                        name: session.name,
                        mentorTasks: [(session)<-[:FROM]-(task:Task)-[:FOR]->(mentor) |
                                        {id:id(task), name: task.name}
                                     ],
                        menteeTasks: [(session)<-[:FROM]-(task:Task)-[:FOR]->(mentee) |
                                        {id:id(task), name: task.name}
                                     ]                     
                      }  
                  ]
       } AS myResult
```

returning

```
{
  "mentor": {
    "name": "Mentor Jill",
    "id": 211
  },
  "sessions": [
    {
      "menteeTasks": [
        {
          "id": 223,
          "name": "Task D"
        },
        {
          "id": 220,
          "name": "Task C"
        },
        {
          "id": 219,
          "name": "Task B"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Session 1",
      "id": 208,
      "mentorTasks": [
        {
          "id": 213,
          "name": "Task A"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "mentee": {
    "name": "Mentee Joe",
    "id": 212
  }
}
```

Note that using the pattern comprehensions, you can avoid the OPTIONAL matches. If a pattern comprehension does not find anything, it returns `[]`